# Making unique link for each row in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on bringing products from database (for each product id name type price ) and want to present these data on table and make the id as link. When clicked on it it will open a new page with the description about that product holds that id.

The problem is that all id's get the same link when click on it.

```
include"connect.php";


$sql= "select * from products where NameP='$product'";
$dbRecords=mysql_query ($sql);

echo "<form  method='post'>";

echo "<th><input type='submit' name='elimnate' value='Elimimar'/></th>";

echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> </td>";
echo "<td> ID </td>";
echo "<td> </td>";
echo "<td> Price </td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td> Type </td>";
echo "<td> </td>";
echo "<td> Quantity </td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td> elimanate </td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td> order </td>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($arrPro = mysql_fetch_array($dbRecords))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<th> <a href='show.php?id=".$arrPro['id'] ."' >" . $arrPro['id']      . "</a></th>";
    $_SESSION['idu']=$arrPro['id'];

    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";

echo "<th>" . $arrPro['price'] . "</th>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<th>" . $arrPro['type'] . "</th>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<th>".$arrPro['quantity']."</th>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' id='chekbox'>"."</th>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='submit' name='id[]' id='button'>"."</th>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo"</table>";
    echo "</frame>";
```

Comment: and the question/problem is?

Comment: @Fred-ii- He wrote "problem that all id's get the same link when click on it"

Comment: the question is how to have a uniqe link for each product not to make all links open same one

Comment: It looks like it should work. Each link has `$arrPro['id']` in the link, and that should be different on each row. What ID are you seeing instead?

Comment: Seconding @Barmar, this code should be providing the desired result. Make sure that show.php is behaving properly.

Comment: yes this code is working but when i bring more then one row from database all the id's show the data of the first row what i want i to show that the first link show data of the first product second link sow data foe second  product but both show data for first product

Comment: Try `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i still have same result :\

Comment: where is `$product` being defined?

Comment: $product is the posted name of product $product=$_POST['name'];

Comment: ah, that is why your query is failing ;-) Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You may start seeing some errors/notices ;-) Edit: I thought you said it wasn't assigned in your original comment. Is that not in your code now?

Comment: No its my code and i wrote this -- or die(mysql_error())  -- in my connect.php file if u noticed i did an include for it i posted the part of the code which i got a problem with

Comment: Maybe the show.php has some problem. Do you check the ids in the links, to be the right ones?

Comment: noo no problem with the show.php

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping the solution was removing    $_SESSION['idu']=$arrPro['id']; because SESSION will store last value and preview it in show.php